# GM_setValue with $_POST value

Tags: php, post, greasemonkey

In Greasemonkey I want to use GM_setValue to set a $_POST value but it won't work.

I tried
`GM_setValue ("username", <? $_POST['email']; ?>);`

but nothing happens if I try it out.
Can anyone help me please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
GM_setValue ("username", <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access GM_setValue from a regular HTML page, you can't emit that statement from your PHP and have it work.

You could do something like

```
<span id="username_span" data-value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>"></span>
```

And have your grease monkey script look for the span and pull the data value out.

```
// Typed from memory, untested.
var username_span = document.getElementById("username_span");
var username = username_span.getAttribute("data-value");
```